# Update old Mysql statement with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can i update this old statement into the PDO statement?

The old one:

```
$query = "UPDATE  tbl_product
          SET
         image = CASE WHEN '$post_image' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH('$post_image') = 0 THEN image ELSE '$post_image' END
```

and the new one PDO

```
$query = "UPDATE tbl_product 
                SET 
                image=:image
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use placeholders in place of every value. `image = CASE WHEN ? IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH( ? ) = 0 THEN image ELSE ? END` then bind `$post_image` 3 times. You can do that in the execute, or with the `bindparam`.

Comment: "then bind $post_image 3 times" what does it mean?

Comment: The driver needs to know what to put in place of the placeholders. This is done with binding. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php `execute(array($post_image, $post_image, $post_image))` might roughly be all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO has the advantage of *named placeholders*. Unlike MySQLi, which only has `?` as a placeholder (PDO has this too), you can use `:image` as a placeholder, and repeat it where necessary - PDO will then substitute the placeholders for the value that is bound to that placeholder, either in `execute()` or by using `bindParam()`/`bindValue()`.

Simply replace all instances of `'$post_image'` to `:image`. Note that there are no quotes around the placeholder.

```
$query = "UPDATE  tbl_product
          SET image = CASE WHEN :image IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(:image) = 0 THEN image 
                           ELSE :image END";
```

Then you'd prepare and execute the query, assigning the `$post_image` value to the `:image` placeholder. Note how that is inside an array `[..]`.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(["image" => $post_image]);
```

Documentation:

- http://php.net/pdo.prepare
- http://php.net/pdostatement.execute

Comment: I thought the name couldn't be reused unless emulation was on.